Configuring XYZ source
I was requested to replace the OSM layer with the company's map proxy. I was hoping to use the XYZ source, but I'm struggling to understand the concept.
I configured it like this:
createMapProxyLayer(): TileLayer<XYZ> {
  this._tileLayer = new TileLayer({
    opacity: BASE_OSM_LAYER_OPACITY,
    source: new XYZ({
      tileUrlFunction: (coordinate, layer, projection) => {
        const extent = projection.getExtent();
        const [width, height] = this.getSize();
        return `https://URL_PLACEHOLDER/mapproxy/service?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&LAYERS=osm&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=${width}&HEIGHT=${height}&BBOX=${extent[0]},${extent[1]},${extent[2]},${extent[3]}`;
      }
    })
  });
  return this._tileLayer;
}

// End of the proxy URL, for easier reading
// ...&WIDTH=${width}&HEIGHT=${height}&BBOX=${extent[0]},${extent[1]},${extent[2]},${extent[3]}`

In the tileUrlFunction I'm getting the extent out of the projection, together with map size and then I'm replacing them in the URL.
When I pan the map, I see the requests are made to the URL and it returns 200, but without any payload. What did I not understand or what did I miss?
EDIT: As @mike suggested, I switched XYZ source to TileWMS source and it's much easier. That's how I configured it.
createTileWMSLayer(): TileLayer<TileWMS> {
  this._tileLayer = new TileLayer({
    opacity: BASE_LAYER_OPACITY,
    source: new TileWMS({
      params: { LAYERS: 'osm', VERSION: '1.1.1' }, // and other params if necessary
      url: 'https://URL_PLACEHOLDER/mapproxy/service',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    })
  });
  return this._tileLayer;
}


It would be simpler use TileWMS https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileWMS-TileWMS.html instead of XYZ as it will create the correct url for you.
If you must use XYZ for a WMS source the url function would look like
  tileUrlFunction: (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) => {
    const tileGrid = this.getTileGrid();
    const [width, height] = toSize(tileGrid.getTileSize(tileCoord[0])).map((d) => d * pixelRatio);
    const extent = tileGrid.getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord);
    const code = projection.getCode();
    return `https://URL_PLACEHOLDER/mapproxy/service?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&LAYERS=osm&SRS=${code}STYLES=&WIDTH=${width}&HEIGHT=${height}&BBOX=${extent[0]},${extent[1]},${extent[2]},${extent[3]}`;
  }


I went with the TileWMS option and it seems like a step forward, but now I'm getting CORS/Opaque Response Blocking. Any idea how to correctly set up crossOrigin parameter?

If the server allows cross origin access it should be sufficient to specify crossOrigin: 'anonymous' in the source options.  As long as you are not using your source in a  WebGLTileLayer you should be able to load images without cross origin access, but you will not be able to export the map.

Thanks, I had to contact the provider about CORS, but the TileWMS really simplified things.
